# How do I `umount` /proc?

Tags: linux, mount, chroot

I am following [this](http://wiki.thincan.org/NAND_firmware_update) tutorial on how to do a firmware update to my NAND flash. I followed it only changing the directory where I am placing my new root. 
I am copying all of the `/bin` `/dev` `/sbin` `/usr` folders into a `tmpfs` that I have located in `RAM`.

The following commands are where I start running into problems:

```
umount /sys
umount /proc
```

If I `killall5` `sys` unmounts without a problem but then when I try to unmount proc it gives me:

```
umount: can't umount /proc: Device or resource busy
```

I have tried using `chroot` similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54312/unable-to-unmount-proc) link on a similar issue. But it doesn't seem to help much.

I tried to chroot to my newroot, using the following command but it then gives me more grief:

```
chroot /tmp/newroot /bin/ash
```

Error:

```
umount: can't umount /proc: Invalid argument
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? I'm getting the feeling I'm missing something trivial, as is ussually the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you probably don't need to unmount `/proc`. The procfs is [not even a real filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs), rather a representation of the contents of memory and the currently running processes. What you want is probably to [bind mount it](http://docs.1h.com/Bind_mounts) to a location inside the chroot:

```
# mkdir -m 0555 /tmp/newroot/proc
# mount --bind /proc /tmp/newroot/proc
```

Comment: This allowed me to do everything I needed to. I successful started running the filesystem from ram and flashed the required `mtd` partition

Answer (score 2):

Install `lsof` if it isn't already, then reboot into single-user mode and say `lsof | grep /proc`. Kill all programs that are still using `/proc`. Then you can unmount it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lazy unmount with `umount -l /proc`, the mount will remain until all references are deleted but will be disconnectd so you can unmount the root (after using `pivot_root`).

Alternatively you could move the mount points using `mount --move`.